# Truecrypt & luks, best from both worlds?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption, luks

I am looking for multi-platform on-the-fly encryption tool, both truecrypt and luks /dmcrypt/ can provide, but I cant have dual boot /Linux&windows/ in this case, because TC does not support multi boot with other than Windows OS and luks is not supported on Windows or am I wrong?

I was thinking about this option:
Have a initram which will mount luks device with encrypted Windows and than start another grub which will chain windows' boot loader is this possible?

Or have you got any better solution?

To be clear I would like to encrypt whole disk, not just part.
Also no readable headers /information about encryption/ in plain text /as luks has/ seems to be like nice to have feature

Comment: [FreeOTFE](http://www.freeotfe.org/) can use LUKS volumes; however, it doesn't support encrypting the boot partition yet.

Comment: Starting GRUB from within Linux will not work. First, the bootloader expects a fresh uninitialized system, but Linux has already initialized all hardware and switched the CPU to 'protected' mode. Second, dm-crypt is a Linux feature. The moment you start Windows, dm-crypt stops working.

Comment: @grawity Well I am OK with non-crypted /boot partition as long as it is just small place with no interesting data.

Comment: @grawity What about to have Windows partitions encrypted with Truecrypt and Linux with Luks and have USB Pen with Grub for linux or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did on an XP system:

- Install Windows, leaving plenty of room for an encrypted Linux partition.
- Do the Truecrypt full disk encryption in Windows and wait until it completes.
- Install Ubuntu on a new partition in free space.  Install to LUKS encrypted partition and remember passphrase.  Do not overwrite your Windows partition.  **Do not install GRUB.**
- Return to Windows, snag a copy of [`grldr`](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/install_windows.htm#windows4) and put the `grldr` file in your C:\ root.
- Add this line near the bottom of your `c:\boot.ini`:

`c:\grldr="GRLDR"`

- Also a good idea to add `Timeout=10` or similar near the top.
- You'll need to make an old GRUB 0.9-style `menu.lst` in "c:\" that points to your Ubuntu installation.  I put Linux on my second partition and my `menu.lst` looks like this:

> ```
>  timeout 0 
>  default 0
>  title grub2 
>  find --set-root /grub/core.img
>  kernel /grub/core.img
>  boot
> ```

The end result is this:

- You turn on your system and get Truecrypt bootloader.  Enter passphrase.
- You are then taken to Windows bootloader, where you can select Windows or GRLDR.  Windows will boot encrypted Windows.  GRLDR will boot Linux.
- Linux will ask you for passphrase if you select it.  So you have to enter two passphrases to boot Linux.  This is not something I minded.

With Vista/7 the process is the same except instead of editing `boot.ini` you need to use `bcdedit.exe`, or another BCD editor, to create BCD entries.  I've not tried this on a Vista/7 system yet.

Comment: Well, this seems nice, I will definitely try it ... and I don't mind entering two pass-phrases it is fine.